# Set a different seed for each run

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot of a function that uses `rand(0)` to generate numbers between 0 and 1.

I would like to set a different random sequence each time I run the Gnuplot script. 
The documentation says to uses `rand(x)` where `x` is a positive integer.

I have tried this

```
rand(floor(10*acos(rand(0))))
```

that gives an integer for each execution.
However, this line gives me an error. I have not found any example of setting the seed of `rand`.

How can I set a different seed each time to get different plots?

Regards

Comment: What is your error? Are you just typing that to see what you get? Then you need `print rand(floor(10*acos(rand(0))))`. That, by the way, is just a convoluted way to get a different set of identical random numbers sequence. Quit gnuplot, start it again, and you will get this new set of random numbers again.

Comment: @DanSp. You are right. If I write `rand(4)` into the script, it tells me `line 0: invalid command`. Doing print from the interactive Gnuplot in Terminal it gives me the same number 0.99...If I run the script from the terminal, the plot is the same each run.

Comment: Anybody know that the value `rand()` returns when run with an argument != 0 means?

Comment: @Karl type `help random` in the gnuplot terminal and it will tell you.

Comment: @DanSp. No it doesn't. The return value for argument !=0 is not explained.

Comment: @Karl It explains that rand(0) returns the next pseudo random number according to the current values of the two internal 32-bit seeds. Does this not make sense? If you are asking how gnuplot does this, it also references a paper on the algorithm it uses.

Comment: @DanSp. Yes, of course. I'm wondering about this: `set samp 100; plot [1:100] "+" us 1:(rand($1))` Does the return value upon seed initialisation have any significance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want seemingly different set of random numbers each time gnuplot starts up you can seed the random number generator with the time(0) function. Use:

```
rand(time(0))
```

the first time to get it going. Then just use rand(0) for the rest in your script.

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually *use* (print the return value, or assign it to a variable) the `rand()` function with a positive integer parameter to seed the generator

```
print rand(-1)
print rand(0)
print rand(-1)
print rand(0)
print rand(5)
print rand(0)
```

`rand(-1)` (or restarting gnuplot) resets the seed to a standard value. What you want, I guess, is to be able to set a pseudo-random *seed*. The usual way to do that is to use the current time and date:

```
 print rand(time(0))
 plot ..... something using the rand(0) function
```

`time()` returns unix time in integer seconds if the argument is an integer, a real with ~ microsecond precision otherwise. So re-running your script with a rate < 1s will sometimes give two identical plots. You might do sth like `rand(int(time(0)*1000)))` to prevent that, although I couldn't imagine why that'd be necessary. ;-)

Comment: @AaronBrick What is odd?

Comment: I meant gnuplot's behavior. The accepted answer doesn't mention why plain old rand(time(0)) doesn't work.

Comment: Not alone like Dan Sp. showed. Thanks for pointing out that print is needed.

Comment: Wull, yea. `rand()` if a function, if you use it as a solitary command, gnuplot just gives you an error and stops.